# How to trigger confetti with if condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a confetti that I am using it with this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-confetti

Here is my template:

```
<template>
         <div>{{ confetti }}</div>
</template>
```

there is an if condition in the button which I need to render that confetti in the same condition:

But I want to use it at the top of my component because I want to use it more efficiently on the full screen.

```
data() {
    return {
      array: [],
      confetti: null,
      confettiEnabled: false,
    };
  },

methods: {
    getArray() {
      this.isLoading = true;

      axios
        .get(`api`, {
          params: {},
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.array = response.data.data;
          this.arrayLength = this.array.length;
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
this.confettiEnabled = true;
      console.log(this.confettiEnabled);
    },
},

mounted() {
    this.getArray();
  },
```

and I created watcher for the component:

```
watch: {
    confetti: {
      handler() {
          if (this.documents.length == 0 && this.confettiEnabled) {
            this.confettiEnabled = true;
            this.$confetti.start();
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.$confetti.stop();
            }, 3000);
          }
      },
      immediate: true, // This ensures the watcher is triggered upon creation
    },
  },
```

But this logic doesnt work even and my confetti never triggers.

Comment: Your code looks perfect to me! It should work. It is going inside this condition `if (this.array.length == 0)` ?

Comment: Actually this code renders the confetti from the beginning (as soon as refresh the page). But I want it come when the condition is true

Comment: This is happening as you added the watcher which invoked immediately on component creation.

Comment: How do you think I should add watcher and what should I do then?

Comment: Can you please explain little more. when you want to show/hide `confetti` to make the picture more clear

Comment: So I want as soon as this.array.length == 0 is true and everytime when it is true

Comment: In that case your code looks good only. As initially your array length is 0 that's the reason it is showing `confetti` and after 3 seconds it will stop as per your code.

Comment: Can you please check again I added confettiEnabled this time but it doesnt work this time

Comment: what is `documents` ? I did not see any property with documents in `data` object. Also, watcher will invoke before mounted. Hence, `this.confettiEnabled` will always be false.

Comment: documents are actually array, I wrote it wrong, fixed it

Comment: Now, Your question is unclear to me. I did not see any reference of `documents`. Giving up now!

Comment: I changed documents with array, it was typo sorry and I changed my question